# Does BigQuery BI engine support left join or not?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

as per the documentation BI engine is supposed to accelerate left join

https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/optimized-sql#unsupported-features

I tried this dummy query as a view, connect to datastudio

```
SELECT xx.country_region,yy._1_22_20 FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_jhu_csse.deaths` xx
left join `bigquery-public-data.covid19_jhu_csse.deaths` yy
on xx.country_region=yy.country_region
```

[image]

my question is: is left join supported or not ?

bug report here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154786936

Datastudio report : https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/25710c42-acda-40a3-a3bf-68571c314650

edit : it seems BI engine is still under heavy development and needs more time to be feature completed, I just materialized my view, but it has a cost, 4 small tables < 10 MB,  that change very 5 minutes cost 11 GB/ day , I guess it is worth it, Datastudio is substantially faster now, you can check it here (public report)

https://nemtracker.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try JOINs, don't try sub SELECTs, don't do queries for BI Engine.

The best practice is to `CREATE OR REPLACE` a table dedicated to the dashboard you're building. Make sure to not have nested/repeated data there either. Then BI Engine will make your reports shine.

Related, check out this video I just made with the best practices for BI Engine with BigQuery:

- https://youtu.be/zsm8FYrOfGs?t=307

Comment: I saw your video and it was great, my data change very 5 minutes, and it is 4 table, schedule query every 5 minutes from 4 tables add up quickly :) , was hoping BI engine fix that

Comment: Yeah, 5 minute changes are not very well handled by Data Studio.

Comment: actually, it works rather well, I just hope datastudio increase the refresh rate from 1 hour to something like maybe 15 minutes like the data sourced from google sheet :), but in general I am happy with schedule query